# How to assign an event handler for DataTemplate in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I try to dynamically create and assign a `DataTemplate` to a `HeaderTemplate` of `DataGrid` through code. To do this I have a method `GetDatatemplate(string fromstring)` that defines an XML literal and then uses this to create a `DataTemplate`. This works fine as long as I don't include the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event handler in the `DataTemplate`.

My `DataTemplate` saved in `string` variable called `StringHeaderTemplate` in code-behind of `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
private string StringHeaderTemplate =@"<DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate.Resources>                  
      <ControlTemplate x:Key=""imgNo"" TargetType=""{x:Type Control}"">
         <Image Source = ""pack://application:,,,/Images/upArrow.png"" />
      </ControlTemplate >
      <ControlTemplate x:Key=""imgUp"" TargetType=""{x:Type Control}"">
         <Image Source = ""pack://application:,,,/Images/upArrow.png"" />
      </ControlTemplate >
      <ControlTemplate x:Key=""imgDown"" TargetType=""{x:Type Control}"" >
         <Image Source = ""pack://application:,,,/Images/downArrow.png"" />
      </ControlTemplate >
   </DataTemplate.Resources> 
   <Grid Background=""Transparent"" MouseLeftButtonDown=""Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown"">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Button Content=""Hello""/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row=""1"" HorizontalAlignment= ""Center"" Text = ""TextBlock"" />
      <CheckBox Grid.Row= ""2"" HorizontalAlignment= ""Center"" IsChecked= ""True"" />
  </Grid >    
</DataTemplate>";
```

And the method which gets `DataTemplate`:

```
private DataTemplate GetDatatemplate(string fromstring)
{
    ParserContext context = new ParserContext();
    context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
    context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
    return  (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(fromstring, context);
}
```

Then I just apply this `DataTemplate` to `HeaderTemplate` of `DataGrid`:

```
private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn_1(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataTemplate dtCell = null;
    DataTemplate dtHeader = null;
    string dtString = string.Empty;
    string dtHeaderString = string.Empty;
    switch(Type.GetTypeCode(e.PropertyType))
    {
        case TypeCode.String:
        dtString = StringTemplate.Replace("xxColumnxx", e.PropertyName);
        dtHeaderString=StringHeaderTemplate;
        break;
    }
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtString))
    {
        dtCell = GetDataTemplateForDataGrid(dtCellString);
        dtHeader = GetDataTemplateForDataGrid(dtHeaderString);
        DataGridTemplateColumn c = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
        {
          CellTemplate = dtCell,
          HeaderTemplate = dtHeader,
        };
        e.Column = c;            
     }
}
```

The event handler is really simple:

```
private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString());         
}
```

The exception I get is a XamlParseException that has an InnerException of type ArgumentException that says:

> "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security
>   transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type."

Any ideas what to do?

**Update:**

I've tried to bind through `Command`, however the `CallSortingCommand` is not called. Maybe you know what I am doing wrong?

```
<Grid Background=""Transparent""> 
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>                 
       <i:EventTrigger EventName=""MouseLeftButtonDown"">                                        
          <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command = ""{Binding 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, 
            Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.CallSortingCommand}"" />
       </i:EventTrigger>             
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>             
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content=""Hello""/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row=""1"" HorizontalAlignment= ""Center"" Text = ""TextBlock"" />
    CheckBox Grid.Row= ""2"" HorizontalAlignment= ""Center"" IsChecked= ""True"" />
</Grid >
```

Comment: What's StringTemplate?

Comment: `private string StringHeaderTemplate =@"<DataTemplate>` omg stop right there... what the heck are you doing?  DataTemplates should be defined within your resources.  If you need custom logic to select a data template, create and use a DataTemplateSelector.  What's going on I don't even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an interesting problem, 'cause possible solution could be in finding object you want to subscribe to in visual tree, after data template is applied. But it is a column and it would be hard to access visual tree in that case.

I'd suggest to go with Interactions, that allow to define event triggers in XAML. Please have a look at the code below:

```
    private string StringHeaderTemplate = @"<DataTemplate>
   <Grid Background=""Transparent"">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName=""MouseLeftButtonDown"">
           <si:CallMethodAction MethodName = ""Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown"" TargetObject=""{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}""/>
         </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Button Content=""Hello""/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row=""1"" HorizontalAlignment= ""Center"" Text = ""TextBlock"" />
      <CheckBox Grid.Row= ""2"" HorizontalAlignment= ""Center"" IsChecked= ""True"" />
   </Grid >    
</DataTemplate>";


    public void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    private DataTemplate GetDatatemplate(string fromstring)
    {
        ParserContext context = new ParserContext();
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("i", "clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("si", "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions");

        return (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(fromstring, context);
    }
```

P.S. Please pay attention to public access modifier of Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown event handler, with private it will not work.

**UPDATE**

Full source code:

*XAML*

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridDataTemplateInCode.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridDataTemplateInCode"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGeneratingColumn="dg_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*C#*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }


    private string StringHeaderTemplate = @"<DataTemplate>
   <Grid Background=""Transparent"">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName=""PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"">             
           <si:CallMethodAction MethodName = ""Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown"" TargetObject=""{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}""/>
         </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Button Content=""Hello""/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row=""1"" HorizontalAlignment= ""Center"" Text = ""Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown"" />
      <CheckBox Grid.Row= ""2"" HorizontalAlignment= ""Center"" IsChecked= ""True"" />
   </Grid >    
</DataTemplate>";


    private string DateTimeWithCommandHeaderTemplate = @"<DataTemplate>
   <Grid Background=""Transparent"">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName=""MouseLeftButtonDown"">             
           <i:InvokeCommandAction Command = ""{Binding DataContext.CallSortingCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}""/>
         </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Button Content=""Hello""/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row=""1"" HorizontalAlignment= ""Center"" Text = ""CallSortingCommand"" />
      <CheckBox Grid.Row= ""2"" HorizontalAlignment= ""Center"" IsChecked= ""True"" />
   </Grid >    
</DataTemplate>";

    private string TimeCellTemplate = @"<DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment= ""Center"" Text = ""{Binding Time}"" />
</DataTemplate>";

    private string DescCellTemplate = @"<DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment= ""Center"" Text = ""{Binding Desc}"" />
</DataTemplate>";


    public void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString());

        var vm = DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;

        vm.Items[0].Desc += "+";
    }

    private DataTemplate GetDatatemplate(string fromstring)
    {
        ParserContext context = new ParserContext();
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("i", "clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("si", "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions");

        return (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(fromstring, context);
    }

    private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTemplate dtHeader = null;
        string dtString = string.Empty;
        string dtHeaderString = string.Empty;

        DataGridTemplateColumn column = null;

        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(e.PropertyType))
        {
            case TypeCode.String:
                {
                    column = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
                    {
                        CellTemplate = GetDatatemplate(DescCellTemplate),
                        HeaderTemplate = GetDatatemplate(StringHeaderTemplate),
                    };
                }

                break;

            case TypeCode.DateTime:
                {
                    column = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
                    {
                        CellTemplate = GetDatatemplate(TimeCellTemplate),
                        HeaderTemplate = GetDatatemplate(DateTimeWithCommandHeaderTemplate),
                    };
                }

                break;
        }

        if (column != null)
        {
            e.Column = column;
        }
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            _collection.Add(new MyObject() { Time = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(i), Desc = i.ToString() });
        }

        CallSortingCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnCallSortingCommand, (o) => true);
    }

    private void OnCallSortingCommand(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("From OnCallSortingCommand");
    }

    public ICommand CallSortingCommand { get; set; }


    private ObservableCollection<MyObject> _collection = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _collection;
        }
    }


    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }     
}


public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }


    private string _desc;

    public string Desc
    {
        get { return _desc; }
        set { _desc = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Desc))); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}



public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, Anton, I'll try it. Could you suggest to read some article about connection between `DataContext` and `Visual Tree`? I feel that it is really important area.

Comment: thanks, Anton, I've tried this approach. Nevertheless, it is not firing `public void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Comment: Moreover, I've tried to use `Command`(**Update** section of my question). Nevertheless, `CallSortingCommand` is not fired.

Comment: Regarding DataContext here is a good point to start: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/using-the-datacontext/. And this article explains possible problem with DataGrid: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Comment: As per code I've provided, it works, and MessageBox with current date is fired. Maybe I should provide full source code for this?

Comment: Ok, I'll update the answer  with full code in a couple of hours. Solution with the Command will also work, if you'll attach DataContext that has CallSortingCommand property of type ICommand. I'll show this in the update as well.

Comment: Updated answer with the full code. Am I right that you want to handle mouse clicks on grid only? Just because current implementation will not fire on clicks on Buton or CheckBox, because they intercept MouseLeftButtonDown bubbling event. If you want your event to fire on all clicks you have to use tunneling events, such as PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown .

Comment: Yeah! You are right! I'll test it tomorrow. The work day is ended:). Thank you!

Comment: Ok, you are welcome, please feel free to ask in case of any questions regarding this solution :)